# Struggling to writing my object to Parcelable

Tags: java, android, android-activity, parcelable

I am trying to send an object from one activity to another, so hence I am using `parcelable`, and while I have created code to send it and receive it,(the code for this is at the bottom) it seems that I need some code to be able to actually write the object to the parcel.

[Error While Passing An Object From An Activity To Another (Using Parcelable)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13787497/error-while-passing-an-object-from-an-activity-to-another-using-parcelable)
I believe what I need to do is similar to the answer given in this, so I need a `writeToParcel` method, which I have done in the code below. (Although at `dest.writeValue(this);` is where I get an error) says StackOverFlowError

I believe i may also need `public static final Parcelable.Creator`... although don't completely know how to write it (I have tried to write one roughly and its the bit in comments)

Also I don't know if I need a bit that would be like `public Clubs (Parcel source)`...

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
public class Clubs implements Parcelable{   
        public void setEvent(String eventType, String date) {
            this.eventType = eventType;
            this.date = date; 
        }

   //contains lots of defined variables and various methods that 
   //aren't relevant for my question and would take up lots of room
   //all like the one above.


        //public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR
        //= new Parcelable.Creator() {
        //    public Parcel createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        //        return (in);
        //    }
        //};

        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
                  dest.writeValue(this);
        }

}
```

My onItemClick class that puts the object into the parcel, and starts the new activity

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                Clubs mymeeting = db.get(map.get(position));
                Intent i = new Intent();
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putParcelable("mymeeting", mymeeting);
                i.putExtras(b);
                i.setClass(ListSample.this, DynamicEvents.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
```

The start of my new activity code that will be edit later once it send the object across correctly

```
public class DynamicEvents extends Activity
{
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        // Create the text view
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(20);
        textView.setText(" " + b.getParcelable("mymeeting").toString());

        // Set the text view as the activity layout
        setContentView(textView);
  } 
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need pareceable and just can't pass the URI to your content or atleast something you could use to find your content? Ideally you would keep this information in a database, remember just because you can.. doesn't mean you should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite `writeToParcel` method as

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(eventType);
    dest.writeString(date);
}
```

You may not be allowed to write Custom Java Object directly. Either write standard data values individually or make your object `serializable` and use method `writeSerializable` on `Parcel` object.