# Find the error: parcelable BadParcelableException

Tags: java, android, parcelable, badparcelableexception

I'm having the famous `BadParcelableException`, but I can't see where is the problem, here is my `Parcelable` class:

```
public class PaymentInfoViewModel implements Parcelable {

    private long idEstablishment;
    private String nameEstablishment;
    private int cardNumber;
    private double cardTotalValue;
    private String cardTotalValueDesc;
    private byte tipPercentage;

    public PaymentInfoViewModel() {
    }

    private static final Parcelable.Creator<PaymentInfoViewModel> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<PaymentInfoViewModel>() {
        @Override
        public PaymentInfoViewModel createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new PaymentInfoViewModel(source);
        }

        @Override
        public PaymentInfoViewModel[] newArray(int size) {
            return new PaymentInfoViewModel[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeLong(idEstablishment);
        dest.writeString(nameEstablishment);
        dest.writeInt(cardNumber);
        dest.writeDouble(cardTotalValue);
        dest.writeString(cardTotalValueDesc);
        dest.writeByte(tipPercentage);
    }

    public PaymentInfoViewModel(Parcel source) {
        setIdEstablishment(source.readLong());
        setNameEstablishment(source.readString());
        setCardNumber(source.readInt());
        setCardTotalValue(source.readDouble());
        setCardTotalValueDesc(source.readString());
        setTipPercentage(source.readByte());
    }
//getters/setters

}
```

It's put here, inside my adapter on event click:

```
    PaymentInfoViewModel p = new PaymentInfoViewModel();
    p.setIdEstablishment(item.getIdEstablishment());
    p.setNameEstablishment(item.getName());
    p.setTipPercentage((byte)0);
    p.setCardTotalValueDesc("");
    p.setCardTotalValue(0);
    p.setCardNumber(0);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, CardNumberActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(ConstantsUtils.PARAM_INTENT_PAYMENT_INFO, p);

    context.startActivity(intent);
```

And how I'm trying to get the class:

```
PaymentInfoViewModel paymentInfoViewModel = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(ConstantsUtils.PARAM_INTENT_PAYMENT_INFO);
```

I have previously checked these links, but I couldn't find a solution:

[Parcelable protocol requires a Parcelable.Creator object called CREATOR (I do have CREATOR)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548077/parcelable-protocol-requires-a-parcelable-creator-object-called-creator-i-do-ha)

[Error While Passing An Object From An Activity To Another (Using Parcelable)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13787497/error-while-passing-an-object-from-an-activity-to-another-using-parcelable)

Edit:
And here goes the error (it happens when I try to `getParcelableExtra`):

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: br.com.soutsapp.Souts_v3, PID: 19841
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.soutsapp.Souts_v3/br.com.soutsapp.Souts_v3.view.activity.CardNumberActivity}: android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcelable protocol requires a Parcelable.Creator object called CREATOR on class br.com.soutsapp.Souts_v3.model.viewModel.PaymentInfoViewModel
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcelable protocol requires a Parcelable.Creator object called CREATOR on class br.com.soutsapp.Souts_v3.model.viewModel.PaymentInfoViewModel
    at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2436)
    at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2358)
    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2264)
    at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2614)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
    at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:786)
    at android.content.Intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.java:5377)
    at br.com.soutsapp.Souts_v3.view.activity.CardNumberActivity.onCreate(CardNumberActivity.java:30)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 0):

After some hours of work and trying lots of things I finally managed to fix it, and it was really simple, the property `CREATOR` cannot have its accessor `private`, I changed it to `public` and it worked!

Comment: how sure are you of this solution??

Answer (score 0):

If you do not know it already, you could be interested in the Parceler library (though you already solved your problem by now): https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler

(I'd comment if I had the reputation)

Answer (score 0):

**In My Case**

I just simply remove my old Parcelable interface code
and implement new Parcelable Interface code.

and it work for me..

***Edit**

Make sure your Parcelable class is static.

**My Model Class**

```
public class AccountModel implements Parcelable {

    private BigDecimal amount;
    private int icon;
    private String name;
    private long id;
    private BigDecimal initial;

    public AccountModel() {
        this.id = new Date().getTime();
        this.name = "Untitled";
        BigDecimal bigDecimal = BigDecimal.ZERO;
        this.amount = bigDecimal;
        this.initial = bigDecimal;
        this.icon = R.drawable.ic_card;
    }

    public AccountModel(BigDecimal amount, int icon, String name, long id, BigDecimal initial) {
        this.amount = amount;
        this.icon = icon;
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.initial = initial;
    }
    public AccountModel( int icon, String name, long id, BigDecimal initial) {
        this.icon = icon;
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.initial = initial;
    }


    public AccountModel(long j, String str, BigDecimal bigDecimal, BigDecimal bigDecimal2, int i) {
        this.id = j;
        this.name = str;
        this.amount = bigDecimal;
        this.initial = bigDecimal2;
        this.icon = i;
    }
    public AccountModel(BigDecimal initial, String name, int icon)
    {
        this.initial = initial;
        this.name = name;
        this.icon = icon;
    }
    protected AccountModel(Parcel in) {
        this.id = in.readLong();
        this.name = in.readString();
        this.amount = BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(in.readString()));
        this.initial = BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(in.readString()));
        this.icon = in.readInt();

    }

    public static final Creator<AccountModel> CREATOR = new Creator<AccountModel>() {
        @Override
        public AccountModel createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new AccountModel(in);
        }

        @Override
        public AccountModel[] newArray(int size) {
            return new AccountModel[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public static AccountModel newCopyOf(AccountModel account) {
        return new AccountModel(account.getId(), account.getName(), account.getAmount(), account.getInitial(), account.getIcon());
    }



    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeLong(this.id);
        dest.writeString(this.name);
        dest.writeString(String.valueOf(this.amount));
        dest.writeString(String.valueOf(this.initial));
        dest.writeInt(this.icon);
    }


    public BigDecimal getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(BigDecimal amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public int getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public void setIcon(int icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public BigDecimal getInitial() {
        return initial;
    }

    public void setInitial(BigDecimal initial) {
        this.initial = initial;
    }
}
```